# Sax Parser - Layout Style

Tags: java, saxparser

I was reading an example of a sax parser being used to get my head around it - I then went and read a second example. The second example had the tags equal to 'open' and 'close' whether as the first example had them set to 'true' and 'false'. Why is that?

```
DefaultHandler defaultHandler = new DefaultHandler(){  

    String firstNameTag="close";  


    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,  
      Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {  

     if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("FIRSTNAME")) {  
      firstNameTag = "open";
```

Why is it set to close first?

Answer (score 0):

The `firstNameTag` variable in your code example is internal to the example implementation; it's not part of the `SAXParser` API. Basic usage of a `SAXParser` will always have some code that executes in `startElement` and manipulates internal state in order to react to the fact that a certain tag has just been opened. The nature of that internal state is entirely up to you.